# Giving custom classes to each TD for styling - Datatables & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, html-table

I'm using [datatables](http://www.datatables.net) for displaying server-side data in tables.

I can't target and style individual cells (`<TD>`) though. I search a bit and found it might be possible with:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
    ....
}
```

... but I'm not quite sure how because I have a few table and not all have the same number of columns and rows. I want to give common class to all `TDs` of a 'column'.

Comment: You should be able to target every first cell of every row, every 3rd cell of every row, to target columns. See CSS pseudo classes : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Using jQuery, right, but how?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `sClass` parameter in Columns definition. For example, if you have 3 columns and want to pass custom class for second and third column, you can:

```
"aoColumns": [
    null,
    { "sWidth": "95px", "sClass": "datatables_action" },
    { "sWidth": "45px", "sClass": "datatables_action" }
]
```

You can check [datatables documentation](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanksss!!

Answer (score 22):

You can use `columnDefs` to define classes for each column.

Example in **coffeescript**:

```
$('table').dataTable(
  columnDefs: [
    {
      targets: -1 # targets last column, use 0 for first column
      className: 'last-column'
    }
  ]
);
```

This is using new API 1.10+.

Comment: This applies the style to the <th> element too

Answer (score 13):

For those who found this question when searching for `fnRowCallback` and want to add styling based on cell content rather than using static css classes, using the `fnRowCallback` will do the trick:

```
oTable = $('#matrix').dataTable({
  ...
  "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
    for (var i in aData)  {

      // Check if a cell contains data in the following format:
      // '[state] content'
      if (aData[i].substring(0,1)=='[') {

        // remove the state part from the content and use the given state as CSS class
        var stateName= aData[i].substring(1,aData[i].indexOf(']'));
        var content= aData[i].substring(aData[i].indexOf(']')+1);
        $('td:eq('+i+')', nRow).html(content).addClass(stateName);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this may be useful for some future visitor :-)

Comment: This works only even rows, why is it ignoring other rows

Comment: Could you post an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ ? I don't see why this would alter every second row. All the script does is: in case a condition is met (inside the `if` statement), the current row and cell number are used to retrieve a JQuery instance of the cell and to alter content and class of the cell. Your problem may be due to your CSS code having `tr:even td` or `tr:odd td` overwriting the style?

Comment: this is a very good soln. However I would like to add the class name to the selected row and not just one cell within that row. Can u plz help with that... thanks.

Comment: @dkjain could you give this a try: `$('td:eq('+i+')', nRow).parent().addClass("NAME");` ?

Comment: Awesome!!! man that works.I pity myself as I am noob in JS, anyways 'll report back if any issues or further query.thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to include above code in Tablepress Wordpress plugin which uses dataTables JS library however I am not sure where to include this in the plugin core files. The tablepress\controllers\controller-frontend.php has 
'<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
{$datatables_strings}{$commands}
});
</script>'. I am not sure where to include the above code in between that script tag...COULD you help out.Thanks

Comment: @dkjain I added a reply to your question on [the Datatables form](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/72433/#Comment_72433), hope that'll help.

Answer (score 12):

Here's how to do it using `createdCell`, using [DataTables 1.10+ syntax](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell).  The benefit of this approach is that you can conditionally style the cells.

```
"columnDefs": [
{
        "targets": [16],
        "createdCell": function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            switch(cellData) {
            case "Pending":
                $(td).addClass('pending');
                break;
            case "Rejected":
                $(td).addClass('rejected');
                break;
            case "Approved":
                $(td).addClass('approved');
                break;
            case "SAP":
                $(td).addClass('sap');
                break;
            case "Reconciled":
                $(td).addClass('reconciled');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
],
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to target the row or an individual cell in a callback:

```
var table = $('#order-history-table').DataTable(
    {
        "ajax": url,
        "pageLength": 20,
        "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {

            // Add a class to the cell in the second column
            $(row).children(':nth-child(2)').addClass('text-justify');

            // Add a class to the row
            $(row).addClass('important');
        }
    }
);
```

I was unable to get the 'createdCells' parameter to work so had to do it through the row.